# Close vote filter is not working

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

I was reviewing close votes with filter "primarily opinion-based", but I found only 2 or 3 questions out of 15 filtered correctly.

Here I am posting one image as example. Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231909/close-votes-review-does-not-honor-the-filter-by-tag

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255476/review-filters-appear-to-be-broken